# format dollar chracter for javascript files in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Im learning angular and it would be nice if i could have $ the dollar sign, formatted so its maybe red since it would make reading angularjs code much easier.I am using visual studio 2013.

To recap.I want the dollar symbol in javascript files to be of color red.

Answer (score 0):

Since this isn't really a question, add your suggestion/request to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com.

If you want to implement this yourself you would need to create your own intellisense settings for JavaScript, which I'd suspect is something you probably don't want to do.